# Set image position on canvas programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code:

```
namespace Game
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Image img = new Image();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myCanvas.Focus();

            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Koala.jpg"));
            img.Width = 100;
            img.Height = 100;              
        }

        public void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(img, 0);
            Canvas.SetLeft(img, 0);
            this.Content = img;

        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
 <Canvas Name="myCanvas" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" Focusable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="166" Margin="118,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
```

When I press a button, the image is shown, as I want to do, but in the center of the window. What I want to do is to set the image on X,Y position I want. How do I do that?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

```
<Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="Foo" Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="200" />
</Canvas>

Foo.SetValue(Canvas.Left, 100);
Foo.SetValue(Canvas.Top, 225);
```

This is my basic test scenario. Sets the image exactly where the `Image.SetValue(Canvas.Position, int)` says to do so.

Comment: But I add the image dynamically, I don't want to set it in the XAML.

Comment: You can still use `Image.SetValue` in your keydown event.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
double left = (Canvas.ActualWidth - img.ActualWidth) / 2;
Canvas.SetLeft(img, left);

double top  = (img.ActualHeight - img.ActualHeight) / 2;
Canvas.SetTop(img, top);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of OnKeyDownHandler method, "this" means MainWindow and so your code will replace its content, whole the visual tree including the Canvas, with the Image. If you wish to add the Image to the Canvas, it should be something like

```
this.myCanvas.Children.Add(img);
```